# Disqus can't work with wordpress' Recent Comments widget

Tags: wordpress, disqus

I installed Disqus comment system on my wordpress. The system itself works well, but wordpress' Recent Comments widget doesn't like it.

The widget(on my sidebar) generate a link to the recent comments. It looks like:

```
http://raintoday.cc/i-hate-two-types-of-people#comment-58
```

But, the real disqus comment link should be:

```
http://raintoday.cc/i-hate-two-types-of-people#comment-230348686
```

The url is wrong. I don't know how to fix.

There is another plugin called [Disqus Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disqus-widget/), but it put too much content on sidebar and can't be customize.

Anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wordpress and Disqus recent comments widgets are designed to pull comments from their respective databases. If you really want full flexibility on the output of the comments, you would have to use the [Disqus API](http://disqus.com/api/docs/) to code your own Wordpress plugin for such a task.

Comment: It's too tiring for a blog. But yes, you answered my question.